# I could not cast initialViewController

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to instantiate a ViewController once after the launching of the app. So I instantiate the controller but than I get a weird error

> Could not cast value of type 'erkeb.HomeVC' (0x100bd8738) to 'erkeb.ContainerVC' (0x100bd8990)

Can someone tell me how to resolve this issue please?

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow?

    fileprivate var containerVC = ContainerVC()

    var MenuContainerVC: ContainerVC{
        return containerVC
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        FirebaseApp.configure()

        containerVC = ContainerVC()

        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

        let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        var intialViewController = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "WelkomVC")

        let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard

        if userDefaults.bool(forKey: "WelkomIntroIsOk"){
            intialViewController = sb.instantiateInitialViewController() as! ContainerVC
        }

        window?.rootViewController = intialViewController
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

        //normaal juist onder lijn 28 maar menu schuift niet open
//        window?.rootViewController = containerVC
//        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

        return true
    }
```

Comment: The *weird* error is pretty clear: The class of your initial view controller is `HomeVC`. And be aware that each call of `ContainerVC()` creates a brand new instance of the class which might not be the instance you expect.

Comment: But in my storyboard I doesn't have a ViewController ContainerVC its only a class so I can't change it via storyboard, how cloud I do it ?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to cast `sb.instantiateInitialViewController()` as `ContainerVC`. If the `UserDefaults` value is true, create `ContainerVC` instance programmatically and assign in `intialViewController`. `ContainerVC` will be assigned as root view controller.

```
if userDefaults.bool(forKey: "WelkomIntroIsOk") {
    intialViewController = ContainerVC()
}
```